# Hive/Impala select and average all rowkey versions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, impala

I am wondering if there is a way to get previous versions of a particular rowkey in HBase without having to write a MapReduce program and average the values out. I was curious whether this was possible using Hive or Impala (or another similar program) and how you would do this.

My table looks like this:

```
  Composite keys          Values 
  (md5 + date + id) | (value)
```

I'd like to average all the values for the particular date and a sub string of the id ("411") for all versions.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You should do the computation on the server, not in the client (Impala or others). Hbase coprocessor endpoints are good for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala uses the Hive metastore to map its logical notion of a table onto data physically stored in HDFS or HBase (for more details, see the [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_concepts.html?scroll=intro_hive_unique_2)).

To learn more about how to tell the Hive metastore about data stored in HBase, see the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-ColumnMapping).

Unfortunately, as noted in the Hive documentation linked above:

> there is currently no way to access the HBase timestamp attribute, and
>   queries always access data with the latest timestamp

There was some work done to add this feature against an older version of Hive in [HIVE-2828](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2828), though unfortunately that work has not yet been merged into trunk.

So for your application you'll have to redesign your HBase schema to include a "version" column, tell the Hive metastore about this new column, and make your application aware of this column.